# AJAX readyState is not changing to 4 in my code

Tags: php, javascript, xml, ajax

This is my code snippet, couldn't understand what's wrong with this as xmlhttp.readyState is not changing to 4.

```
document.getElementById("opencloseimg").src = "images/minus.jpg";
//The page we are loading.
var serverPage = "calendar.php";
//Set the open close tracker variable.
showCalendar = false;
var obj = document.getElementById(objID);
xmlhttp.open("GET", serverPage,true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        obj.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

Comment: Where did you define `xmlhttp`?

Comment: There are good jQuery libraries available for use nowadays. Use them and avoid this clumsy `xmlhttp` stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because the URL you are fetching is not available?

Do you see any errors in the JavaScript console?

Put a message display at the beginning of your statechange function :

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log ('xmlhttp : ' + xmlhttp.readyState + ', ' + xmlhttp.status);
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      obj.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
```

See what is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the response status code is not 200, it could be 304 (not modified) etc.